# Prolog DCG with variables

Tags: prolog, dcg

I have DCG sentences with two persons, representing a male and a female. I want to refer to the person metioned in a previous sentence using "he" or "she".

Suppose we have these DCGs:

```
father --> [Peter].
mother --> [Isabel].

child --> [Guido].
child --> [Claudia].

verb --> [is].
relation --> [father, of].
relation --> [mother, of].

pronoun --> [he].
pronoun --> [she].

adjective --> [a, male].
adjective --> [a, female].

s --> father, verb, relation, child.
s --> mother, verb, relation, child.
s --> pronoun, verb, adjective.
```

Querying `?- s([Peter, is, father, of, Guido], []).` returns `true`.

How can I make sure that when I query now for `?- s([he, is, a, male], []).` should return `true` only because I already mentioned Peter (a male) in the previous sentence. Otherwise it should return `false`.

This question uses the same example as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56135477/prolog-dcg-with-arguments).

Comment: Of interest: [Definite Clause Grammars Examples](https://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~gini/prolog/dcg.html)

Comment: Of interest: Norvig [Chapter 20](https://github.com/norvig/paip-lisp/blob/master/docs/chapter20.md)

Comment: You also need to add the `'` that were put in the other answer. `Peter` is a variable, `'Peter'` is an atom. See: [write_canonical/1](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=write_canonical/1)

Comment: The idea is to add facts like `male('Peter')` and go from there. Once that is working, then remove the fact and get one sentence to convey the idea to the other sentence. Might need to have first sentence assert facts, or view the   two sentences as one semantic idea that have an implied operator between the sentences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can augment your DCG to keep some state (the gender of the last sentence):

```
father --> ['Peter'].
mother --> ['Isabel'].

child --> ['Guido'].
child --> ['Claudia'].

verb --> [is].
relation --> [father, of].
relation --> [mother, of].

pronoun(he) --> [he].
pronoun(she) --> [she].

adjective --> [a, male].
adjective --> [a, female].

s(G) --> s(none,G).

s(_,he) --> father, verb, relation, child.
s(_,she) --> mother, verb, relation, child.
s(G,G) --> pronoun(G), verb, adjective.
```

And now you can chain queries using this state:

```
?- phrase(s(G1),['Peter', is, father, of, 'Guido']), phrase(s(G1,G2),[he, is, a, male]).
G1 = G2, G2 = he
```

You may want to modify a bit the DCG to constrain the relations (using the Gender parameter). For example you DCG currently accepts `'Peter' is mother of 'Guido'` which I'm not sure was intended.